# Are illegal installs showing up in Google Play Developer console for paid apps?

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play console shows Current/Total installs of my paid app, but the thing that bothers me is if current installs are actual number of people who paid for app and didn't get refund within 15 minutes, or it could include hacked app users? My Current installs are around 60 %, so the other 40 % must have used refund option right after purchasing. But is there a way to be sure that I will get my earnings for those 60 % of installs?

Comment: This question appears to be about Google app store policy and implementation rather than about programming.